# No location prompt on iPhone 3G

Tags: iphone, ios4, location

I am developing an iPhone app which uses location services. When I run it on the simulator and my iPhone 4 it works just fine. However, when I test it on my old iPhone 3G I never get the prompt asking me if I want to allow location services for the app. Also, when I go to location settings for the phone the app is not even on the list of apps using location services.
I should note that the code implementing location was basically copied from one of my old apps which works perfectly, also on iPhone 3G.

The phone is running iOS 4.2.1 and my Deployment Target is set to iOS 4.2.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably there is something wrong in your device try this and launch your application again:

> Go to Settings > General > Reset. Then choose “Reset Location Warnings”. A warning pops up and says that this will reset all the location warnings. Click Reset Warning.

please let me know if the problem persist.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but no change. I also tried uninstalling and redeploying the app. Still no prompt and it `[CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]` still returns 0. And it is still not found on the list of apps using location.